# SVG image tag not working

Tags: xml, svg, xampp

I'm playing around with the SVG tutorial [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag), and can't load an image.  XAMPP is giving me an error that says

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

I've copypasta'd from the docs, but it still doesn't work.  Code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="5cm" height="4cm" version="1.1"
     xmlns="localhost" xmlns:xlink= "localhost/svgtest">
    <image xlink:href="My_Image.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="50px" width="50px"/>
</svg>
```

Googling the error message tells me that the XML is broken somehow, but I haven't changed anything but the locale and image title.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You got the namespaces wrong.

change

```
xmlns="localhost" xmlns:xlink= "localhost/svgtest"
```

to

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```

Maybe you should have a look at this [Namespaces Crash Course](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course) by MDN.

Comment: Thanks.  I had assumed that namespace needed to be where I was operating.