# How to display SVG with <use>

Tags: html, css, wordpress, svg

I am trying to use `<use>` tag to display an SVG. I am using Wordpress and have the file under the upload folder (as any other media). For some reason the `<use>` doesn't show, on the browser it show width and height as 0, even though I have inlined them in it.

My code:

```
<svg viewBox='0 0 153 91'>
 <use href='https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/arrow.svg' width='30' height='18'>
</svg>
```

In the Browser:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 153 91">
  <use href="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/arrow.svg" width="30" height="18">
  </use>
</svg>
```

The svg file:

```
<svg fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="9.17" viewBox="0 0 153 91"><path d="m18.898 45.191h115.04"/><path d="m108.181 18.898 25.757 26.293-25.757 26.293"/></svg>
```

BONUS: Could the SVG be inlined somewhere in the `<body>` instead of the file uploaded?

Comment: Yes you can include SVG directly in the body, also `<use>` should point to a fragment not another SVG as evident from the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use

Comment: I had read the doc. I understand the idea, but cannot understand why it is not showing in the browser.

Comment: the reason is because your svg file is the entire svg, you need the inner content of that svg

Comment: What's the inner content should be like?

Comment: aah my bad the attribute you are looking for is `<image></image>` instead of `<use/>`

Comment: Still Not working.

Comment: make sure the svg image is a valid one

Answer (score 0):

This was missing on the SVG

`xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`

Final SVG should be:

```
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
    <symbol id="arrow" viewBox="0 0 153 91" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="9.17">
    <path d="m18.898 45.191h115.04"/><path d="m108.181 18.898 25.757 26.293-25.757 26.293"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

src: [SVG image tag not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104324/svg-image-tag-not-working)